# How to skip onepage checkout shipping information?

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, shipping-address

I have created a new option as `pickup @ office` in onepage billing section instead of the other two options `Ship to this address`
`Ship to different address`. If customer selects this `pickup @ office` option he can use any address for the billing address. But the shipping address will be set progametically. I have done up to this step. What I want to do next is to directly move to the `shipping methods` section by skipping `shipping address`. For this is there a better way except overriding OnepageController.php.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I'm about to tackle something similar in the near (less than a month) future. So if I solve it I'll post the answer! (that said the shipping option is selected after billing/shipping addresses is selected in a normal one page checkout)

Comment: @Barry Carlyon : Sorry to say. But I still couldn't find the way. But Instead I did something like this. User will redirect to Shipping Information section but he cannot do any modifications there. I disabled all the fields in that section. According to your problem I think you will have to override `saveBillingAction()` in `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`. But I'm not sure whether this will cause more other problems while solving your one. If you prefer the solution achieved by me, even though it's not the exact solution I'll put it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this was the only solution I was able to find. 
Need to override the controller `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`

> config.xml

```
<config>
 . . . . . .
    <global>
            <rewrite>
                <test_cart> <!--This can be any unique id -->
                    <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/onepage/#]]></from>  <!-- the URL which u want to override-->
                    <to>/mymodule/onepage/</to>  <!-- destination url -->
                </test_cart>
            </rewrite>
             . . . . . 
    </global>
    . . . . . . 
</config>
```

> app\code\local\Mynamespace\Mymodule\controllers\OnepageController.php

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';

class Mynamespace_Mymodule_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
public function saveBillingAction()
 {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
//            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
//            $data = $this->_filterPostData($postData);
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
            $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);

            if (isset($data['email'])) {
                $data['email'] = trim($data['email']);
            }
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);

            if (!isset($result['error'])) {
                /* check quote for virtual */
                if ($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'payment-method',
                        'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                    );
                } elseif (isset($data['use_for_shipping']) && $data['use_for_shipping'] == 1) {
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping_method';
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'shipping-method',
                        'html' => $this->_getShippingMethodsHtml()
                    );

                    $result['allow_sections'] = array('shipping');
                    $result['duplicateBillingInfo'] = 'true';
                } else {
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping_method'; // set the checkout step which you want to move
                }
            }

            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
}
}
```